# Scroll background content if modal is open in ionic V3

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

If I am open popup alert or custom modal view controller , still background content is scrollable, I don't want to scroll that background content if pop/modal is open.

I have tried below links :

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/popover-background-still-scrollable/59874/3

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/issues/11712

Still not found any solution.

Answer (score 0):

in .html file :

```
 <ion-content  #scrollArea >

 </ion-content>
```

in .ts file :

```
 @ViewChild('scrollArea') mainContent: Content;
```

and set true by this method when modal open and set false when modal dismiss....

```
 private setDisableScroll(disable:boolean)
 {
    let scroll = this.mainContent.getScrollElement();
    scroll.style.overflowY = disable ? 'hidden' : 'scroll';
 }
```